# List and files in python

Tags: python, list, file

I'm using `readlines` method from python to get list of all data lines. Now I wan't to access some index from that list:

```
file = open('article.txt', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
print data.index(1)
Error: data isn't a list
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Re-read the error message: It's not "data isn't a list" but rather "x not *in* list"

Comment: BTW, cool that you're currently at exactly 1,337 karma. I dare not upvote your question :)

Comment: @tim-pietzcker Sorry, I just wasn't near my computer. I always mark questions which help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean (if your goal is to print the second element of the list):

```
 print data[1]
```

`data.index(value)` returns the list position of `value`:

```
>>> data = ["a","b","c"]
>>> data[1]          # Which is the second element of data?
b
>>> data.index("a")  # Which is the position of the element "a"?
0
>>> data.index("d")  # Which is the position of the element "d"? --> not in list!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

Comment: And if the objective is to print the first line in the input file, use `print data[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you mean `print data[1]` not `print data.index(1)`. [See the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)